# Space between axis line and axis label ios MPChart

Tags: ios, objective-c, charts

In my iOS app in Objective-C I used [Charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/) library for implementing chart, but I need to increase the space between x-axis line and label (marked in red line on image) how to increase it.
 please help.

[image]

Comment: Can you please add some more detail like screen shots or what you need to achieve ?

Comment: @CodeChanger updated question with image please check.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For above `XAxis` and `leftAxis` you need to change `offset` property of axis as mention below :

```
//For left Axis
lineChartView.leftAxis.xOffset = 20.0;

//For XAxis
lineChartView.xAxis.yOffset = 20.0;
```

By this you can achieve offset in your `Axis`.

**Check this image with 20.0 offset value:**

[image]

Hope this will helps.

Comment: hi. by converting chart 2.2 to 3.0 some changes in code occur. in old code able to pass xvalue array. but in new how to pass it.

Comment: Please ask new question as its out of topic for this thread. Thanks